# attributing an id to a variable with jquery

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm trying to assign the value of an list item id to a variable then use that variable and change the whole set-up of the webpage with some jquery function. But for now I'm just trying to test the whole thing and log out the new value of the variable.

I read here to use .attr('id') but I keep getting undefined. here is a part of the html code:

```
    <ul class="vilains">
        <li id="Joker"><img src="image/Joker.jpg" alt="The Joker"></li>
        <li id="Lex Luther"><img src="image/Lex%20Luther.png" alt="Lex Luther"></li>
        <li id="The Trixter"><img src="image/The%20Trixter.jpg" alt="The Trixter"></li>
        <li id="The Kingpin"><img src="image/The%20Kingpin.png" alt="The Kingpin"></li>
    </ul>
```

I know superheros...it's just to play around and test my knowledge....

here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".vilains").find("li").on("click", function (){
        var ennemy = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(ennemy);
    });   

});
```

log is always undefined.
What I'm I doing wrong?
Also would it be possible to get the value of alt in the image?

Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly fine from what I can see.

Comment: I dont see a problem here. it works fine and not undefined http://jsfiddle.net/yhvzatgf/

Comment: If the HTML elements are dynamically inserted/added, use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: the DOM handles this naturally. `this.id` is much simpler and micro-optimizes your code.

Comment: What does the debugger point to as undefined? Also, while this code "works" in that it prints what you expect, whitespace in id isn't valid

Comment: Which browser are you trying this code in?

Answer (score 0):

There you go :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".vilains li").on("click", function (){
      var ennemy = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log(ennemy);
      console.log($(this).children('img').attr('alt'));
   });   
 });
```

Here's a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/38zvrypg/3/

Comment: The above is a better approach but the original code isn't 'wrong'.

Comment: if log is undefined before, with this code it will still be undefined, the original code using find is probably faster

Comment: Try the fiddle it works perfectly for me... I'm not sure if find is faster then the direct selector you execute one more method.